# Cannot create home folders on the server for network accounts

Tags: macos, network, finder, permission, server.app

I have a problem with creating home folders on the server for network accounts. The goal is to share the same files on multiple devices. A quick overview of what I do:

1. I go to the Server.app.
2. I create a folder (in my case on /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Network Users).
3. I enable the File Sharing service.
4. I add the /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Network Users as a shared folder.
5. Once added, I edit it and make sure it is able to be used for home folders (AFP).
6. I create a new network account and set his/her home folder location to 'Network Users'.

When I try to log in on a device (in my case a MacBook Pro), it gives me the following error saying I can't login:

You are unable to login to the user account "williamdedwards" at this time.
Logging in to the account failed because an error occurred.

I am 100% sure that this is related to the permissions. When I add my user account manually and give it Read/Write access to the 'Network Users' folder, it *used* to work (not anymore, I still get the same error now). When I set the home folder to 'Local', I can login and everything is fine.

I also came to this conclusion with Apple Support.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something with the authentication process of the clients. Open Directory needs to be running on the server (try to delete and rebuild it) and this server must be assigned as a directory server in the the clients account preferences. You might be able to check permissions by accessing the a home folder via CMD-K and the AFP:// URL from the Finder of any client. If you get read/write access then permissions should be okay.

Comment: I found out that all home directories have Read/Write permissions for the user they're meant for. Would a video of what I'm exactly doing be helpful?

Comment: Don't know if a video would help that much. Usually you need to look at the log files and see, what's going (wr)on(g). There are a few more questions: Is the user in question also the owner of the home directory? Are you using domain names or IP addresses?

Comment: Where are the log files located? As for your questions, I'm not sure where I can see the owner of the folder in the GUI. Binding to the Open Directory is done with the .private (the Server.app is set to Internet and VPN).

Comment: I meant the log files on the clients. Just see under "All Messages" in the Console there. That will be the most interesting part here.

You can see the owner of a folder in the Server App: Server -> (your server) -> Storage -> navigate to the shares in question and select it. The gear symbol at the bottom shows the permissions. The first one is the owner (2nd = group, 3rd = others). If the server is named "server.private", can you do a successful lookup / reverse lookup from the clients on server.private?

Comment: DNS lookup:  dig server.private | DNS reverse lookup: dig -x 192.168.xxx.xxx

Comment: `Williams-MacBook-Pro:~ server$ ping server.cyberfusion.private
ping: cannot resolve server.cyberfusion.private: Unknown host`

The client is bound to Open Directory with the local IP though:

`Williams-MacBook-Pro:~ server$ ping 192.168.2.9
PING 192.168.2.9 (192.168.2.9): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.9: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=57.853 ms`

Comment: Okay, it gets complicated. DNS must work properly to for a stable setup. Depending on what's your nameserver (usually your router/gateway), you need to configure name resolution there or at least a DNS alias to your server. An other approach would be to setup DNS on the server and put the server's IP address in the client's network settings as an additional nameserver beside existing one(s). There is an excellent guide on ars technica for Yosemite Server, including the OD and DNS setup: [link](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/11/a-power-users-guide-to-os-x-server-yosemite-edition/)

Comment: Sorry, wrong link - it's on crypted.com: [link](http://krypted.com/mac-security/setup-the-dns-service-in-os-x-yosemite-server/)

Comment: That's something I totally forgot; thanks! I'll try this tomorrow and let you know if it worked or not. I guess I'm also going to reset my entire server, it's a mess...

Comment: Alright, so I've fixed this. It was indeed related to the hostname which was not correct. I'm not sure why I could log in when the File Sharing service was not used for home folders, even though the hostname was set incorrectly then as well. I am not sure if I should accept your answer, as it were especially the comments that helped me. I am still confused about one thing though: when the server cannot be accessed from outside the network, how could I access the VPN from outside the local network? It says that the VPN service is available at the .private hostname...

Comment: I'd rather not set the server so it could be accessed from outside the local network without a VPN (Internet), as that would prevent a lot of security issues and having to worry about it...

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! Well, the login process is not very complicated. The authentication instance (your server) is being asked if the given credentials are valid and when there's no remote home folder, it's just a usual local login procedure. --- When you want to access the server from outside via VPN you have to setup port forwarding on your router/gateway for the VPN ports. (Usually 500, 1701/1723, 4500 all UDP.) Securing the server on other ports is rather a question of secure passwords, encryption and an up-to-date system.

Comment: Alright, so I decided not to mess with all that, so I reinstalled my OS X (just to be sure nothing would go wrong) and set it to use a domain name. I have one question left though: I'm posting this from my MBP, from a network account, and everything seems to be working absolutely fine! Thanks!

Comment: I'm definitely going to accept your answer when you answer the following question though: ... eh, I forgot the question. Give me a moment.